# SlickGrid callback onRowSelect?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I want to add a callback when the user selects a row in the table, but I can't figure out how to do so...

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.event.drag.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slick.core.js"></script>
    <script src="slick.rowselectionmodel.js"></script>
    <script src="slick.grid.js"></script>
    <script>
        var grid;
        var columns = [ /* my column definitons */ ];
        var options = {
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            enableColumnReorder: false,
            enableAddRow: true
        };

        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('/actions/unit_list.php', function (data) {
                grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
                grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
                $('#myGrid').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

With this, I can select the row (as per [this example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html)), but I've no idea how to add a callback when the rows are selected (preferably something that returns the row id(s), since I want to use those to load something else on the page).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahh, after reviewing more of the code on [example 6](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html)--specifically the interaction of the remotemodel--I see that I have to call the triggered function like this:

```
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function() { console.log(grid.getSelectedRows()); });
```

From here, I can use `grid.getSelectedRows()` to return the selected rows, as @Tin pointed out.

Comment: run into same thing, thanks for the answer. (One more thing, it requires importing slick.rowselectionmodel.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can get selected rows by calling `grid.getSelectedRows()`.

Comment: But that isn't a callback, it's just a public function to return the selected rows. I want to fire a function as soon as a user clicks on a row. How would I do that?

Comment: Or am I wrong? I tried something like `grid.onSelectedRowsChanged = function() { alert('something happened!'); };`, but I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { alert('something happened!'); } has no method 'notify'`...